# how to make the zip code not mandatory in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I'm trying to make the zip code NOT mandatory in PrestaShop™ 1.5.6.1 with no luck.
I've tried updating the db field need_zip_code and modifying the options at the country tab.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if that's what you have tested when you speak about the "country tab", but to choose if Prestashop must ask or not for the zip code, you must:

- Go to Localization > Countries
- Choose the country for which you want to remove the zip code
- Set Need zip/postal code to NO
- Save

Zip code will no more be mandatory.

Comment: This will remove the Zip Code entirely. Personally, I'd like to make it show up but not force the user to input a value in there...